# cocos2d schedule selector error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, schedule

i have an error when scheduling a method. (to display how many star you get according to your score. i have addStar0 addStar1 addStar2 addStar3 methods)

```
[self schedule:@selector(addStar0) interval:0.2f];
```

and the methods are:

```
-(void) addstar0 {
    [self unschedule:_cmd];

    if (star > starProgress) {
        starProgress++;
        [self schedule:@selector(addStar1) interval:0.5f];
    }
    else {
        [self schedule:@selector(displayResult) interval:0.5f];
    }

}
```

error message:

```
Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt
```

I've tried changing all my methods into addStar1: (ccTime) delta and schedule: @selector(addStar:) interval: 0.2f, but still the same. (actually i've used both ways to schedule( with/without parameter), and both of them worked well in my last project. )

also, one weird thing: sometimes i can't use [self schedule: something], but [CCScheduler sharedScheduler] schedule: something] works fine. I guess it may be project settings or so?

Please answer it with code. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 'addStar0' for selector

```
[self schedule:@selector(addStar0) interval:0.2f];
```

then

```
-(void) addstar0 {
```

should be

```
-(void) addStar0 {
```

Comment: !!!you are right! can't believe i get such a nonsense error message, instead of something like: 'incomplete implementation' or 'addstar not found'...

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is actually on `[self unschedule:_cmd];`

Where is _cmd defined? Try commenting out that line and running it again.

Comment: `_cmd` is a special hidden variable that is passed to every method. It is the selector of the current method.

Comment: of course, i schedule: @selector(addStar0) and unschedule it inside addStar0 itself.

Comment: dunno where _cmd defined, but it is the selector of current method.

Comment: nope, loading forever, the framerate drops to 47.6 fps,  and still the same error message. (everything is the same as last time.

Comment: @Josh, a little more detail - _cmd is part of the Objective-C runtime, passed as a parameter to every selector call.  It contains the selector information - that's NSException knows what selector you tried to call when you have an unrecognized selector -- it reads it out of the _cmd variable.

Answer (score 0):

put  `[self unschedule:_cmd];` after the else statement